# How to implement a BaseActivity in mvvm architecture? Without using dependency Injection

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mvvm

I am currently learning MVVM architecture.
I tried to make a `BaseActivity` class.

My `BaseActivity`:

```kotlin
abstract class BaseActivity<ViewModel : BaseViewModel, Binding : ViewDataBinding> :
    AppCompatActivity(),
    EventListener {

    lateinit var binding: Binding
    private var viewModel: ViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutid)
        this.viewModel = viewModel ?: getViewModel()
        binding.setVariable(getBindingVariable(), viewModel)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
 
    @get: LayoutRes
    abstract val layoutid: Int

    abstract fun getViewModel(): ViewModel

    abstract fun getBindingVariable(): Int
  
    private fun getViewModelClass(): Class<ViewModel> {
        val type = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
        return type as Class<ViewModel>
    }
}
```

Now I am using this `BaseActivity` in my `SplashActivity`:

```kotlin
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity<SplashActivityViewModel, ActivitySplashBinding>() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel

    override fun onFailure(message: String) {}

    override fun onStarted() {}

    override fun onSuccess() {}

    override fun getViewModel(): SplashActivityViewModel {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SplashActivityViewModel::class.java)
        return viewModel
    }

    override fun getBindingVariable(): Int {
        return BR.splash_viewmodel
    }

    override val layoutid: Int
        get() = R.layout.activity_splash
    
}
```

I have used following answer as a reference to implement my `BaseActivity.kt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289334/how-to-have-generic-viewmodel-in-baseactivty-class
But I am getting a **blank white screen** while running the app.

Can someone please tell me what is the problem here or how to make this `BaseActivity` (without using dependency injection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have overridden the wrong `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
```

I did play around with something like that few years ago, you can find my approach [here](https://github.com/bblackbelt/BindingsCollections/blob/master/bindings/src/main/java/com/blackbelt/bindings/activity/BaseBindingActivity.kt)